# i am using Android Studio 3.2v and i am getting this error when i run my main_activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update your SDK and SDK Tools please.

Comment: This answer may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206640/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithinstantrunfordebug?rq=1

Comment: @Young Soyinka : tried this already it is not working

Comment: @Umang: Everything is upto date...

Comment: Tried almost everything still the error shown in the attached images is there.. Plz Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NoClassDefinationFound error

Means that it couldn't find class `com/google/protobuf/message`. Perhaps you missed one of the dependencies in the `Build.gradle` which is related to `com/google/protobuf/message`. You can try to add this dependency however:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.0.3

Which seems to be related.

- Also, use `implementation` instead of `compile`.
- Try disabling multidex or, update it to the latest version
  ([1.0.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/multidex/1.0.3)).